# Google Cloud Function Node.Js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Cloud function waits for a file to land in a bucket and loads it to BQ. The BQ table already exists. My datasetid is undefined even though I assign the dataset name in the top of the function. Any ideas on what my issue could be?

Following Function returns the following error.
Error: function crashed. Details:
Cannot read property 'table' of undefined

```
{
  "name": "sample-cloud-storage",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "repository": "googleapis/nodejs-bigquery",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "1.2.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "1.5.1",
    "yargs": "10.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/nodejs-repo-tools": "2.1.3",
    "ava": "0.24.0",
    "nyc": "11.3.0",
    "proxyquire": "1.8.0",
    "sinon": "4.1.3",
    "uuid": "3.1.0"
  }
} 

exports.ToBigQuery_Stage = (event, callback) => {
  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49111829/using-cloud-function-to-load-data-into-big-query-table-it-is-appending-to-the-t

  const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
  const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  const file = event.data;
  const context = event.context;
  const projectId = "bi-sales-sms";
  const datasetId = "bi-sales-sms:BI_Sales_SMS";
  const bucketName = file.bucket;
  const filename = file.name;

  //const dashOffset = filename.indexOf('-');

  //const tableId = filename + "_STAGE";
   const tableId = 'Roll_Up_Daily_Sales_Per_Retailer';

  console.log('hello norman');
  console.log('Load ' + filename + ' into ' + tableId);

const metadata = {
  allowJaggedRows: true,
  skipLeadingRows: 1

 };

  //test the print
  console.error(BigQuery.Dataset(datasetId));

  BigQuery
//issue is here  
    .Dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .Load(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename),metadata)
    .then(results => {
      job = results[0];
      // Wait for the job to finish
      return job;
     })
    .then(metadata => {
       // Check the job's status for errors
      const errors = metadata.status.errors;
      if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
        throw errors;
      }
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Job " + job.id + " completed.");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });


  callback();
};
```

Comment: Hi @N0RM1NAT0R, I provided an answer that I believe solves yiur issue. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client creation is missing, add this to your code to set it

```
const bigquery = new BigQuery({
   projectId: projectId,
 });
```

Now instead of the `BigQuery` object you should use the `bigquery` client object.

Also, to create a reference to an existing dataset use `bigquery.dataset(datasetId)` and not `bigquery.Dataset(datasetId)`.

More information about the BigQuery Node.js Client Library can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.3.x/).